# Bash: fixed variables change to changing variable

Tags: bash

I am writing code which has to pick a specific line from the table.
I am trying to pick the line and then put in a file with the name `result_X_Y.txt`.

I already tried `$X`and `$Y`.
Maybe there are some other options?

There is the line of code:

```
line=$(grep -F '21.581' cuted.txt | grep -F '54.6845')
```

this works very well when I put the numbers, but if I want to use these lines it does not work:

```
X=21.581

Y=54.6845

line=$(grep -F 'X' cuted.txt | grep -F 'Y')
```

Comment: Use $x instead of x.  `grep -F "$X" cuted.txt`

Comment: And as Guru & qwsj showed, use *double* quotes (`"$x"`) not single quotes (`'X'`).

Comment: As an aside, do you know which is first on the line, and what delimits them? We could improve this to one pattern instead of executing `grep` twice. Likewise, is this happening in a loop of some sort? There's probably a more efficient way, though we'd need more info to know for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using grep with word X and Y, but it not a variable.

Try it: `line=$(grep -F "$X" cuted.txt | grep -F "$Y")`

Comment: line=$(grep -F "${X}" cuted.txt | grep -F "${Y}") I used like this and it worked. Thank you!